# Building and flashing OpenWRT on beaglebone black

Tags: flash, sd-card, openwrt, beaglebone

I am trying to make a custom build of OpenWRT for beaglebone black board and flash on to an SD card. I have managed to compile the OpenWRT distribution using a docker build environment (https://github.com/noonien/docker-openwrt-buildroot) but I am unable to figure out how to flash on to the SD card. The build output includes an image file called `openwrt-omap-am335x-boneblack-ext4-sdcard.img.gz` - can I use `dd` or the `etcher` program to write to an SD card and boot with it? I have tried exactly this, but didn't work. It appears from instructions from OpenWRT site (specifically https://openwrt.org/toh/texas.instruments/beagleblack) that the flash needs to be pre-partitioned into a bootloader partition and a firmware partition? The instructions are very confusing and unclear, so I'd appreciate some pointers on how to load the binary images onto the SD card. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

dd it to SD card like this (just replace /dev/sdb with actual sdcard device)

```
zcat bin/targets/omap/generic/openwrt-omap-am335x-boneblack-ext4-sdcard.img.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb bs=4096 conv=fsync
```